# Script to automatically open URL contained in mail

Tags: google-chrome, email, url

I am looking for a way to automatically open in chrome an URL link contained in specific mails, as soon as they arrive. 
Those mails always come from the same address mail (abc@xyz.com), with a similar title, and they contain only one URL link with the same beginning: " http://www.abcd.com/..."

I'm using the app mail on a mac.
I created a rule in mail:
If a New mail arrives and the address contains "abc@xyz.com"
Then run Script "XXX".

I now can't seem to find a way to make this script work. I could use AppleScript ou JavaScript, but I was told Javascript will be better for this purpose. What do you think?

Comment: Show your script(s)